# Python Pandas: Create new column by matching one column value to a different row [i] and column if a separate column on row [i] equals col one value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the very wordy title. I have a df which looks like this:

```
df:
         username     user_id    subreddit_id   subr_fav_by
0       'John69'      1          1              '5illycat'           
1       'John69'      1          2              'adsgd'           
2       'Harry12'     2          3              '5illycat'           
3       'adsgd'       3          4              'John69'           
4       '5illycat'    4          5              'John69'
```

I want the df to look like this:

```
df:
         username     user_id    subreddit_id   subr_fav_by   subr_fav_by_id 
0       'John69'      1          1              '5illycat'       4     
1       'John69'      1          2              'adsgd'          3 
2       'Harry12'     2          3              '5illycat'       4    
3       'adsgd'       3          4              'John69'         1  
4       '5illycat'    4          5              'John69'         1
```

So I want to create a fifth column which is the 'user_id' from the row that contains the 'author' which matches the string in the 'subr_faved_by' column.

I originally tried:

```
for i in range(len(df['user_id'])):
    for j in range(len(df['subr_fav_by'])):
        df.loc[j,'subr_fav_by'] = df.loc[i,'user_id'].where(df.loc[j,'subr_fav_by'].str.contains(df.loc[i,'username']))
```

but got the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

which I tried looking up, but couldn't find what would help me in this specific situation.

So I then tried:

```
df['subr_fav_by_id'] = df['subr_fav_by'].map(df.drop_duplicates('username').set_index('username')['user_id'])
```

But I am not sure why this only returns NaN in the 'subr_fav_by_id' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` and `drop_duplicates()` with `iloc[:,-1]` to just add on the last column.

```
df['subr_fav_by_id'] = df.merge(df[['username', 'user_id']].drop_duplicates(), 
                                how='left', 
                                left_on='subr_fav_by', 
                                right_on='username').iloc[:,-1]
df
Out[1]: 
     username  user_id  subreddit_id subr_fav_by  subr_fav_by_id
0    'John69'        1             1  '5illycat'               4
1    'John69'        1             2     'adsgd'               3
2   'Harry12'        2             3  '5illycat'               4
3     'adsgd'        3             4    'John69'               1
4  '5illycat'        4             5    'John69'               1
```

Comment: Do you know how I could update the code if the same subreddit_id was repeated across multiple rows accompanied by different subr_fav_by strings?

Comment: @elsa for this problem, `subreddit_id` is irrelevant for dropping duplicates and merging. I.E. that column could contain any series of numbers, and the data in all other columns would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df.merge(df[['username', 'user_id']].rename(
    columns={'username':'subr_fav_by', 'user_id':'subr_fav_by_id'}), how='left')
```